# determining if variable based on database query is null in php

Tags: php, postgresql, if-statement

I have the following snippet of php code in which I am trying to have the output be NULL if the php query does not yield any results but if it does yield results I have the output to be NOT NULL.

```
 $dbconnSrc = pg_connect("host=$dbhost dbname=$dbname user=$dbuser password=$dbpass") or die ("Could not connect");

$sql="select area, radius from circle where level>50"; 

$res = pg_query($dbconnSrc, $sql);
var_dump(isset($res));
echo "$res\n";
while($row = pg_fetch_array($res, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $radius=$row["radius"];
    print "radius is $radius\n";
    if (isset($radius)){
        echo "NOT NULL\n";
    }
    else
    {
         echo "NULL\n";
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not getting the desired results, so I was wondering if anyone knows who to tweak this code to get the desired results.

Comment: Are there actual rows in the table with radius IS NOT NULL and level>50 ?

Comment: Your missing a double quote at the end of your SQL statement. Besides that, are you getting the expected results when you run that SQL through a client/command line?

Comment: is that missing quote just a bad paste? btw, did you leave the post? someone posted an answer for that missing quote, did you know that?

Comment: Your question seems unclear based on your code. Why are you looping over each result -- if you only care whether you have results or not (which is a simple IF-ELSE) ? It seems like you are trying to do something other than what you stated.

Comment: @Mikey I noticed the edit fix. The OP isn't responding to my comment above (or any other comments), so we don't know if it's missing or not from their code. An answer was also provided for it, whether or not it will still be there, well... you won't be able to see it if it gets deleted. As you said; the question is (a tad) unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$radius will always be set because you're setting it.

Try this instead.

```
$dbconnSrc = pg_connect("host=$dbhost dbname=$dbname user=$dbuser password=$dbpass") or die ("Could not connect");

$sql="select area, radius from circle where level>50"; 

$res = pg_query($dbconnSrc, $sql);
var_dump(isset($res));
echo "$res\n";
while($row = pg_fetch_array($res, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))
{
    // using $row directly here - no need to create another variable
    print "radius is " . $row['radius'] . "\n";

    // inspecting $row here for the entry first, then to see if it's empty
    if ( array_key_exists( 'radius', $row ) || empty( $row['radius'] ) ){
        echo "NOT NULL\n";
    }
    else
    {
         echo "NULL\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used PostgreSQL functions but, looking at the documentation, you want to use [pg_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-all.php) to fetch all the results at once.

```
$result = pg_query($dbconnSrc, $sql);

// get all the results
$arr = pg_fetch_all($result);

// note that null or empty array are falseys
if ($arr) {
    echo "NOT NULL";
} else {
    echo "NULL";
}
```

[Falseys in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)

Answer (score -1):

You forgot a `"`.

Replace this

`$sql="select area, radius from circle where level>50;`

with

`$sql="select area, radius from circle where level>50";`

Comment: it's most likely a bad paste.